# My c++ Crashes When Calling My Enqueue Object Function

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have a program that performs discrete time event simulation. I have modeled this by using a linked list that I use to enqueue the next events. The main logic of the code is inside a while loop that runs for some n amount of things completed. When this number is low enough, it will finish the loop. However, with enough iterations, it will eventually stop working. I placed various debug statements to see where the issue was, and it was within my `enqueueEvents()` function, a function that inserts an object into my linked list sorted by time, head being the soonest, and the tail being the latest.

The program outputs ERROR POINT J, but not ERROR POINT K, leading me to suspect that something is wrong with the `if((head == NULL) || (head->event_arrival_time > tempNode->event_arrival_time))`.

But I cannot think of what in C++ would make the program simply stop. I'm not looking for someone to simply fix my issue, but would love some insight on why this might be happening.

CODE:

```
void EventHandler::enqueueEvent(Process p_input, int type, float event_arrival_time)
{
    if (debug_mode) {cout << "ERROR POINT I" << endl;}

    Node* tempNode = new Node(p_input, type, event_arrival_time);
    Node* current = head; //Iterable Node

    if (debug_mode) {cout << "ERROR POINT J" << endl;}
    if((head == NULL) || (head->event_arrival_time > tempNode->event_arrival_time))
    {
        if (debug_mode) {cout << "ERROR POINT K" << endl;}
        tempNode->next = head;
        head = tempNode;
        tail = tempNode;
        return;
    }
    while (current->next != NULL && current->next->event_arrival_time <=      tempNode>event_arrival_time) 
    {
        current = current->next; 
        if (debug_mode) {cout << "ERROR POINT L" << endl;}
    }
    
    tempNode->next = current->next;
    current->next = tempNode;
}
```

I originally had not set the first node = to tail in this portion of the function:

```
if((head == NULL) || (head->event_arrival_time > tempNode->event_arrival_time))
{
    if (debug_mode) {cout << "ERROR POINT K" << endl;}
    tempNode->next = head;head = tempNode;
    tail = tempNode;
    return;
}
```

I have placed various debug points to see where the program stops.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] to get a comprehensive answer. If you really wants to consult crystalballs, then please include runtime call stack error or no one could help you. IMHO, using **debugger** should be suffice in this case. Second, why do you need a handmade Queue while you may leverage `std::queue`?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I brand new to Stack Overflow, and a novice progammer, so I am unfamiliar with the standards of debugging complex code. As for not using a queue library, I am used to implementing the queues myself, as per standard in school assignments. I am gonna isolate the class in a separate file and debug there. Thank you for your valuable input.

Comment: You may simplified your project like [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/WseTsM8YG) in godbolt.org. It helps me tons of times for isloating the problems.

Comment: Still, I suggest to learn how to use debugger. Keywords: "How to debug with <your-compile-name-or-ide-name>". Also get your implemented queue unit tested is another good practice.

Comment: You suggest that with enough iterations, your `enqueueEvent` function crashes. However, that does _not_ guarantee this function is the problem. If you happen to also be _dequeuing_ stuff, that might be the cause. As part of your investigation, you should consider this as a possibility and test for it. It could even be your class constructor is not initializing stuff. Who knows? We can only guess here, with a limited view of your program.

Comment: One clear error in your code is the expression: `current->next->event_arrival_time <= tempNode>event_arrival_time` -- I'm certain you intended `tempNode->event_arrival_time` in there. If your queue assumes a particular ordering to function correctly, then this error potentially breaks your ordering and might lead to issues.

Comment: Of further note: instead of duplicating your ordering logic (which as I showed above is broken in one place), it might be more robust to simply your empty-list case and have the ordering logic in only one place. Then, finish the function with: `if (current == head) head = tempNode;` -- and you almost certainly need to update the tail anyway: `if (tempNode->next == NULL) tail = tempNode;`

Comment: I think my '-' was missing in my pasted code, because I have that in mine. That simplified logic makes sense, thanks!

Comment: I am learning to use the debugger and seeing the spot my program stops working is due to a segmentation fault at: if((head == NULL) || (head->event_arrival_time > tempNode->event_arrival_time))

Comment: @CarsonHolland `head` is an invalid but non-null pointer. This is caused by something in the rest of your code.

Comment: @CarsonHolland *As for not using a queue library, I am used to implementing the queues myself, as per standard in school assignments.* -- To be honest, these types of restrictions make no sense if the overall goal is far greater than implementing a linked list or queue class.   If your goal is to implement time event simulations, that is enough work as it is without having to fight with home-made buggy linked lists/queue classes.   The school / teacher should be honest and admit that this homework is a "write a queue class" in disguise.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your valuable input.  I think I'm simply gonna use the c++ queue library to ensure I'm using functions that have been well tested. You all have brought valuable insight into my issues. Thank you!